# After Update Asp.net version 1.1 doesn't support UseDeveloperExceptionPage

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I updated from Asp.net 1.0 to 1.1 and lost the use of the functions.

```
UseDeveloperExceptionPage()
UseExceptionHandler()
```

in my Startup.cs.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UseDeveloperExceptionPage` and `UseExceptionHandler` extension methods are located in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics assembly.
Ensure that you've:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
  ...
},
```

entry in your project.json file and all of the references was successfully resolved.